# Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'. > aidl is missing

Tags: android

This is my build.gradle (MyApplication).

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

> Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugAidl'. > aidl is missing

I got this error. How can i fix this?
Help me.

Comment: Android Studio ->Build ->clean project , then again build your project It will work.

Comment: Thanks for help. I did it, but not work for me. :)

Comment: oh sad ! Please try upgrading your build tool version.

Comment: Yes, Thanks.
My Studio is up to date. but i need update to my build tool.

Comment: You mean. Tool > Build Tool.

Comment: Thanks to you so much. (Solved) :)

Answer (score 4):

Generally this problem will occur when you are trying to build gradle in lower version. Please update your build tool version to latest i.e 23.0.1, It will work

Answer (score 4):

[image]

I solve my issue, set the build tools version from 21.1.2 to 22.0.1, hope it can help who meet the same.

Comment: It didn't fix for me. Someone else knows how to fix it?

Comment: You always have to set it to the latest Build Tools

Answer (score 0):

Kindly upgrade your build tools version to latest.
Also check if you are using any library if it i using older build tools version, upgrade that too.